# TextBox for windows universal - event for delete button?

Tags: c#, xaml, events, textbox, win-universal-app

I use standart TextBox  in my windows universal app. When  I enter text to TextBox 
appears button delete.

[image]

I need a press event to button delete. It should simply be, but I found nothing. Or do I just go to sleep :)

update:

I solved this problem by binding properties of the text.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you want to do with the `Tapped` event on the delete button? And are you using data binding?

Comment: thank you, I solved this problem by binding properties of the text.

Comment: Good. That's what I thought! :)